# magento increment bundle product quantity on options page

Tags: ajax, magento, cart

I am building an on-line store to sale sweets. I added sweets box as bundle products. Before buying sweet, customer has to select box first. each box will have limit on quantity. for example box 1 contains 4 sweets, box 2 contains 12 etc. After selecting box, on options page, suppose I selected box 1. I selected 4 sweets. now I want to buy few more sweets. so there is a need to have an Ajax call to increment box quantity.Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is my advice that you find a different way. I think you are suggesting using ajax to change the product (to a different bundle) and then move the 4 sweets from the initial bundle to the new bundle. That is a very complicated thing to do. An full answer here would need many lines of code.

I suggest you allow the user to pick the sweets first, then ask them to pick a box - the box must be big enough so you might give your box products an attribute sweets_maximum and set that to 4 or 12 and use some logic to only display boxes that are big enough.

Then maybe the cost of the sweets is zero and the boxes non-zero (so you can apply the price for the box and not the sweets).

Alternatively, load the sweet_maximum and the bundle SKUs and all the sweets skus into one webpage and after the user selects the number of sweets, write code to pass back to Magento the correct SKUs to add to the cart ie 10 different sweets SKUs and the SKU for box 2.

Bundles are very complex. I don't think you want to be ajaxing them back and forth.

****EDIT following comment below***

Then this (from my answer above) is my recomendation: do everything in the browser and then pass back to Magento only the box and sweets chosen - your Javascript would form the URL to the bundle controller with the appropriate product selections.

*Alternatively, load the sweet_maximum and the bundle SKUs and all the sweets skus into one webpage and after the user selects the number of sweets, write code to pass back to Magento the correct SKUs to add to the cart ie 10 different sweets SKUs and the SKU for box 2.*

If you really want to use ajax you are going to be jumping through a lot of hoops. Here is the psuedo code I would use. You can find the functions by using the defualt Magento theme and capturing the submission URLs from the bundle pages and the cart-updates and reading the code in the controller actions.

```
(server side)display the chosen bundle
(browser side)UI logic to decide when a different box is needed

NO, WAIT. Maybe we need more information; it is difficult to do a full code architecture in this forum.
//new psuedo code
Carry on as normal. Allow the user to pick any box and any number of sweets through out the entire shopping experience
Eventually the user will visit its cart.
As part of the cart display logic, count the total sweets and count the total box capacity. If box capacity < total sweets, prompt the user to choose a bigger box.
```

Why do I say this? I mean there is a lot of shopping scenarios to work out but if you are really doing these as bundles then the bundle is not in the cart until the user presses the add to cart button - that is why I say the browser should have the logic to change the box in the browser without ajaxing anything. Can a user buy sweets separately?

I don't know what to say. I am happy to help you but we are opening a can of worms as far as the logic is concerned and without a specific list of all shopping scenarios and all allowed buying logic I find it difficult to assist. But I think if you write down all the logic you will find the answer yourself. Don't be afraid to advise your client on different ways to do this.

The URL for adding a bundle to the cart is:

```
POST http://54.247.95.57/checkout/cart/add/product/13831/ HTTP/1.1
product=13831&related_product=&bundle_option%5B767%5D=3867&bundle_option_qty%5B767%5D=1&
```

The URL for removing a bundle is :

```
POST http://54.247.95.57/checkout/cart/updatePost/ HTTP/1.1
update_cart_action=update_qty&cart%5B48677%5D%5Bqty%5D=0
```

But I still say do it all in the browser.

Comment: thanks Malachy but this is what  requirement from client. i must have to select box first then sweets and dynamically we have to enter box and sweets.